# Can't access enumerands of nested private enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

**EDIT:** OK, sorry folks. False alarm. This is Intellisense telling me that it's wrong, but when I extract this into a compilable file, it compiles fine (even though Intellisense still complains).

---

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 to compile a C++ class with some internal state; (let's say) **color** and **texture**. Each has a limited number of valid values, so I'm using good old type-safe enums, and because each enum includes a `None` value, I'm using the new C++/11 syntax; `enum class`, so the enumerands will be scoped to the enum type and not the containing class:

The `Color` and `Texture` types are implementation details, so I'd prefer not to make them public, but making them private prevents me from accessing any of the enumerands.

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    enum class Color {
        None, Red, Green
    } _color;

    enum class Texture {
        None, Smooth, Rough
    } _texture;

public:
    MyClass()
        : _color(Color::Green)
                 ---------- <== ERROR: Member is inaccessible
        , _texture(Texture::Rough)
                   -------------- <== ERROR: Member is inaccessible
    {
    }
};
```

If `Color` was a private nested *class* definition, I could include a 'friend class MyClass' declaration within the inner class, but no such syntax seems to be valid for an enum.

Can someone explain why this isn't working, and how it's *supposed* to be done?

Comment: [Compiles for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b2328d31637cec7).

Comment: What compiler are you using?  How are you compiling?

Answer (score 1):

your code is OK!

it seems that your IDE does not support for C++11

try to enable C++11 on your IDE

Comment: If it didn't support C++11 then `enum class` would've failed.

Comment: enum class makes warning. i have compiled the code and it was ok!

Comment: *You* compiled the code but not the OP. He could be using a different compiler. And I don't see how using `enum class` gives a warning.